# Multiplicative Second Derivative

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to understand the following equation:

$f^{**} = e^{(\ln \circ f^*)'(x)} = e^{(\ln \circ f)''(x)}$

The equation was found in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252380988_Multiplicative_calculus_and_its_applications) paper.

I understand the first equality, which arises from the fact that the multiplicative derivative can be computed as

$f^{*}(x) = e^{(\ln \circ f)'(x)}$

where you plug in $f^*$ for $f$, but I don't understand the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f^*=\exp([\ln \circ f]')$, plugging into the first equality gives:

$f^{**}(x)=e^{\{\ln\circ \exp([\ln \circ f]')\}'(x)}=e^{[\ln \circ f]''(x)}$

Since $\ln \circ \exp([\ln \circ f]')=[\ln \circ f]'$.

Some of your confusion may come from the fact that in your first equality, you mean $f^{**}(x)=e^{(\ln\circ f^*)'(x)},$ or equivalently $f^{**}=\exp{[(\ln\circ f^*)']}.$ When dealing with complicated formulas using prime notation it is important to note whether the variable is explicitly stated.